# Why is Fermi energy considered most probable energy that electron posses in solids?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, conductors, metals, fermi-energy

[image]

It can be seen in graph that probability of electron occupying a energy level below $E_{f}$ is $>\frac{1}{2}$, then why it is said that Fermi energy is considered as most probable energy that electron posses?

Comment: Solids at room temperature have a Fermi energy much bigger than thermodynamic temperature, so the Fermi sphere is only a little perturbed. There are more momentum states close to the sphere's surface (and all these states have basically the Fermi energy). Therefore, Fermi energy is the most probable.